The density of the biggest integer set without given difference
Given fixed positive integers $a_1<a_2<a_3<...<a_k$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $S_n$ as the biggest set $S\subseteq\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\}$ which satisfies that for all $x,y\in S$ and $i\in\{1,2,3,\cdots,k\}$, $x-y\ne a_i$. I want to know $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{|S_n|}{n}$.

I've already solved the case where $k=2$ by the following method:
First assume $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$. Then put $1,2,\dots,a_1+a_2$ on a circle:
$a_2\mathrm{mod}(a_1+a_2)+1,2a_2\mathrm{mod}(a_1+a_2)+1,3a_2\mathrm{mod}(a_1+a_2)+1,\cdots,(a_1+a_2)a_2\mathrm{mod}+1$.
On this circle, every two adjacent numbers have a difference in the set $\{a_1,a_2\}$. So we can't pick any adjacent numbers on the circle, which means we can only pick at most $\lfloor\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\rfloor$ numbers in $1,2,\cdots,a_1+a_2$, and so in $$c(a_1+a_2)+1,c(a_1+a_2)+2,\cdots,c(a_1+a_2)+a_1+a_2$$
for any $c$, which means $\frac{S_p}{p}<\frac{p+a_1+a_2}{p}\frac{\lfloor\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\rfloor}{a_1+a_2}$. We can pick all the number that mod $a_1+a_2$ equals one of the $\lfloor\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\rfloor$ numbers, so the answer is $\frac{\lfloor\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\rfloor}{a_1+a_2}$ when $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$.
If $\gcd(a_1,a_2)>1$, mod $\gcd(a_1,a_2)$ turns the problem into the case above with $a_1=\frac{a_1}{\gcd(a_1,a_2)},a_2=\frac{a_2}{\gcd(a_1,a_2)}$.

I tried some simple cases of $a_1,\cdots,a_k$ and get the following results:

$1,2,6\to\frac27$
$2,3,4\to\frac13$
$2,3,5\to\frac27$
$3,4,5\to\frac38$
$1,3,4,5\to\frac14$
$2,3,4,5\to\frac27$
$3,7,8,9,10\to\frac5{18}$


What may the answer be?

for $k=1$ it is always $1/2$. I do not understand your reasoning for $k=2$ though. It seems to me that you are taking way more than you can.

with 2,3 we can pick 1,5,6,10,11,15,16,20,... and it gives 2/5.

How did you get those results for simple cases with $k>2$? are they proven?

I find $S_{100}$ by linear programming and look for the the period of the numbers in $S_{100}$. Once I got the construction of the result, it's easy to prove it.

So the answer is dependent to the given $a_i$'s?

@VezenBU Yes, the answer is dependent to the given $a_i$'s.

Very interesting problem. I can't imagine there would be a nice closed form formula for $k\geq 3$, which leaves us to developing an algorithm to find the best packing in $S_p$ where $p$ is the period. I think we can upper bound $p$ by $\sum a_i$, so a trivial algorithm will have a complexity of $O(2^{\sum a_i};\cdot; k\sum a_i)$

@EnEm Can you tell me how you prove there's a period? I don't even know how to prove the existence of the limit.

You seem to already be assuming periodicity in your proof for $k=2$

Oh yeah I also assumed it implicitly without thinking. I don't think we can prove periodicity for any general $S_n$, but given one, we can construct another biggest set $S'_n$ which will start having a period after leaving some finite number of elements in the start

I didn't assume periodicity for $k=2$. I've updated the proof.

I am not sure if there is a closed-form answer to your question (I suspect not). Here is an algorithm that should compute the exact answer in roughly $O(4^{a_k})$ time.
Let $m = a_k$. Build a weighted directed graph $G$ whose vertices are the $2^{m}$ $m$-bit binary strings (i.e., elements of $\{0, 1\}^{m}$). We define the edges of $G$ as follows:

Given a node $v = (b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{m})$, always add an edge from $v$ to the node $w_0 = (b_2, b_3, \dots, b_{m}, 0)$. Give this edge weight $0$.
We sometimes connect the node $v$ to the node $w_1 = (b_2, b_3, \dots b_{m}, 1)$ when we do, we give it weight 1. We add this edge whenever none of the bits $b_{m+1 - a_i}$ equal 1.

Now we can think of the construction of a valid set $S_n$ as a walk of length $n$ on this graph, where we consider adding the numbers $1, 2, \dots, n$ to our set in order, and each time we add a number we take a $1$ edge and each time we don't add a number we take a $0$ edge (the constraints on the $1$ edges guarantee that the resulting set is valid).
So you are essentially asking for the asymptotic value of the largest average weight of a walk of length $n$ in this graph. It is well-known (and easy to show) that this is just the maximum average weight of a cycle in this graph (you can decompose any walk into several cycles and a non-cyclic portion of length at most number of vertices). There exist simple algorithms that can compute the maximum mean cycle of a strongly connected directed graph with $V$ vertices and $E$ edges in time $O(VE)$ (e.g. this algorithm, but with adjustments to compute the maximum mean cycle instead of minimum). We have $E = V = O(2^m)$, so it would take $O(2^{2m}) = O(4^{a_k})$ here.  Note that this also shows that the answer is a rational number (with denominator at most $2^{a_k}$).
There might be some way to optimize this to be a better exponential in $a_k$ (e.g. $2^{a_k}$). I am not sure if it is possible to do better than this (e.g. a polynomial-time algorithm or a closed-form solution).
